# Componente Parallax - Materializecss e Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, materialize, single-page-application, parallax

Estou utilizando em uma pagina, angularjs e materializecss.
Estou fazendo o esquema SPA do angular, na minha index.html tenho um menu e um footer sendo que entre eles tem a tag `<div ng-view></div>`

Utilizo $routeProvider para fazer o direcionamento para a pagina. Ai está o problema. 
Na minha rota '/' possuo um Parallax(componente do materialize css), este componente deve ser iniciado conforme documentação do materialize, porém inicio em um script propio na pagina e nao funciona, assim:

```
init.js

(function($){
  $(function(){
    console.log('passa');
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

e faco a chamada normalmente no index.

```
index.html
<script src="/assets/js/init.js"></script>
```

Desta maneira funciona se o parallax estiver no meu html principal, porém como está em um outro html e esta sendo chamado pelo angular não está sendo iniciado e não funciona.

Já tentei colocar no controller da pagina e ocorre o seguinte erro:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at r.fn.load

Alguem ja passou por algo assim? Sou iniciante em programação Web... Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Problema foi resolvido inicializando desta maneira

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
      $('.parallax').parallax();
    });
```

No controller da pagina que possui esses componentes.